# Best alternative to a typedef for a function template?

Tags: c++, templates, function, typedef

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
template <class DataType>
DataType myFunc(DataType in)
{
   ...
}

typedef myFunc<int> myFunc_i;

myFunc_i(37);
```

...however, typedefs cannot be used for functions like this in C++.  What I was wondering is... what are people's preferred alternatives in this case? The only ones I can think of are:

1) Just deal with it, and always use myFunc syntax
2) Manually create a wrapper function, ie

```
inline int myFunc_i(int in)
{
    return myFunc<int>(in);
}
```

This would work, but would have the downside of requiring extra maintenance, and the possibility that it would get out of sync (ie, if you change the function signature for myFunc).

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand, why not just call the specialization directly `myFunc(37);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `decltype`:

```
template <class DataType>
DataType myFunc(DataType in)
{
   ...
}

using myFunc_i = decltype(myFunc<int>(0));

myFunc_i(37);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It is equivalent to "using myFunc_i = int;". See RiaD's answer for the correct version.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
typedef int (*myFunc_i_type)(int);
myFunc_i_type const myFunc_i = &myFunc<int>;
```

This will trigger a compiler error if the signature of `myFunc` ever changes. Making it `const` also prohibits reassigning. Function pointers are also callable like any normal function: `myFunc_i(5)`.

If you don't want a compiler error but rather have it update itself, use `auto` (again with `const`):

```
auto const myFunc_i = &myFunc<int>;
```

Answer (score 10):

Some may disagree, some may jerk their knees against this, but consider this option:

```
#define myFunc_i myFunc<int>
```

As far as macros go, this one is quite safe; the only danger is that someone could redefine or undefine it later.

Aside from that, it has all the advantages of `auto const myFunc = myFunc<int>;`. If you want `auto` but don't want to use C++0x features yet, this is a more portable way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: That's... honestly, one of the best uses I've seen for preprocessor macros in C++.  It can work well with C99/C++11 variadic macros, too, such as if you want to be able to explicitly specify function template parameters without having to type them out each time.  For example, `#define myFunc_allSameType(a, ...) myFunc<decltype(a)>(a, __VA_ARGS__)` on MSVC or `#define myFunc_allSameType(a, ...) myFunc<decltype(a)>(a, ##__VA_ARGS__)` on GCC.  Not always useful, but helpful in cases where there are a lot of template parameters, and they're all either known beforehand or determined from arguments.

Comment: This *is* a real answer. Other's are using external variables, which is not a kind of "typedef"s.

Answer (score 7):

Code Example:

```
#include <iostream>


template <typename T>
T sqr(T a){
    return a*a;
}

auto s = sqr<int>;
int main() {

    std::cout<<s(3.9);
    return 0;
}
```

prints 9, that means that used int function
`auto` requires c++0x, you may use real typename instead, but it's ugly and you'll need check changing signature too.
Besides, this code, may disallow your compiler to inline this function

- As for me, it's often better use full name with `<>`
- In your case you need not use `<>` because `myFunc` is enough(`DataType` may be got from argument type)

Comment: Your example does not compile for me... by "requries c++" did you mean requires c++0x, or microsoft?

Comment: @PaulMolodowitch, I mean c++0x, of cource, sorry for carelessness

Answer (score 4):

I would make a just tiny improvement over Xeo's answer.

Instead of using:

```
auto const myFunc_i = &myFunc<int>;
```

I would use

```
constexpr auto myFunc_i = &myFunc<int>;
```